# Incorrect shape pandas DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to read a list of 489 csv files into pandas data frame using the following code

```
symbols = ['489 symbols']
def data(symbols):
    dates=pd.date_range(start_date,end_date)
    df=pd.DataFrame(index=dates)
    for symbol in symbols:
        df_temp=pd.read_csv('/home/furqan/Desktop/USSP/{}.csv'.format(str(symbol)),usecols=['Date','Price'],
                            parse_dates=True,index_col='Date',na_values=['nan'])
        df_temp = df_temp.rename(columns={'Price': symbol})
        df=df.join(df_temp)
        df=df.fillna(method='ffill')
        df=df.fillna(method='bfill')
    return df
start_date = '2006-01-01'
end_date = '2016-12-31'
data_frame = data(symbols)
test = data_frame.loc['2006-01-01':'2006-12-31',:]
```

I expect the test data frame to have a shape of (365,489) but the shape turns out to be (9874, 489), can't figure out why?

Suppose instead of using 489 elements I use 1 element, in other words if I read one csv file instead of 489 I get the correct shape of (365,1).

Answer (score 1):

Following code worked

```
def data(symbols):
    dates=pd.date_range(start_date,end_date)
    df=pd.DataFrame(index=dates)
    for symbol in symbols:
        df_temp=pd.read_csv('/home/furqan/Desktop/USSP/{}.csv'.format(str(symbol)),usecols=['Date','Price'],
                            parse_dates=True,index_col='Date',na_values=['nan'])
        df_temp = df_temp.rename(columns={'Price': symbol})
        df_temp = df_temp.loc[~df_temp.index.duplicated(keep='first')]
        df=df.join(df_temp)
        df=df.fillna(method='ffill')
        df=df.fillna(method='bfill')
    return df
```

But still can't get what is being duplicated?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need append to `list of Dataframe`s in each loop and last [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
symbols = ['489 symbols']
def data(symbols):
    dfs = []
    for symbol in symbols:
        df_temp=pd.read_csv('/home/furqan/Desktop/USSP/{}.csv'.format(str(symbol)),usecols=['Date','Price'],
                            parse_dates=True,index_col='Date',na_values=['nan'])
        df_temp = df_temp.rename(columns={'Price': symbol}).ffill().bfill()
        dfs.append(df_temp)

    return pd.concat(dfs, axis=1)

start_date = '2006-01-01'
end_date = '2016-12-31'
data_frame = data(symbols)
test = data_frame.loc['2006-01-01':'2006-12-31',:]
```

Also if necessary add values from `date_range` add [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
symbols = ['489 symbols']
def data(symbols):
    dfs = []
    for symbol in symbols:
        df_temp=pd.read_csv('/home/furqan/Desktop/USSP/{}.csv'.format(str(symbol)),usecols=['Date','Price'],
                            parse_dates=True,index_col='Date',na_values=['nan'])
        df_temp = df_temp.rename(columns={'Price': symbol})
        dfs.append(df_temp)

    dates=pd.date_range(start_date,end_date)
    return pd.concat(dfs, axis=1).reindex(dates, method='ffill').bfill()

start_date = '2006-01-01'
end_date = '2016-12-31'
data_frame = data(symbols)
test = data_frame.loc['2006-01-01':'2006-12-31',:]
```

Comment: raise InvalidIndexError('Reindexing only valid with uniquely'
pandas.indexes.base.InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects

Comment: And firs solution working? Hard to know what isproblem without data :(

Comment: Are data confidental?

Comment: both result in same error,and consumes almost consumes 98% of RAM, data is not confidental

Comment: Is possible test solution with 3-4 files only?

Comment: will work perfectly alright with two or three data files

Comment: So problem should be small RAM :( solution should be concat only first 100 files, save to csv, then next 100... Or upgrade RAM (what is most time impossible)

Comment: will try breaking it into chunks and doing it